# C#: Elegant way of copying native dependencies next to my exe

Tags: c#

Currently I am using a post-build event command line similar to this one:

```
xcopy /Y /R d:\svn\some\directory\somedll.dll  $(TargetDir)
```

The problem is this: when others check the code out to another directory they will have to fix the path in this command. Is there a less hackish way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `d:\svn\some\directory` is at a fixed location relative to your `.sln` file, you can use a relative path something like this:

```
xcopy /Y /R $(SolutionDir)..\directory\somedll.dll $(TargetDir)
```

(Note that the value of `$(SolutionDir)` includes a trailing backslash.)

Answer (score 5):

If `d:\svn\some\directory` is within your solution folder then you can add `somedll.dll` to your Visual Studio solution and set *"Copy to Output Directory"* to *"Copy always"* in the file properties.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using the command line in a post-build event you can use actual msbuild tasks as part of the build script by editing the `.csproj` file.

Here is [RichieHindle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319709/c-elegant-way-of-copying-native-dependencies-next-to-my-exe/1319732#1319732) using an msbuild task rather than xcopy:

```
<Target Name="PostBuild">
    <Copy
        SourceFiles="$(SolutionDir)..\directory\somedll.dll"
        DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)"
        />
</Target>
```

In the `.csproj` file you should see a commented out stub for pre/post build targets.